# Element-wise operation with lambda (pd.DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, elementwise-operations

Trying to subtract a constant array from a DatraFrame using lambda.

This is my DataFrame `d`:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame()
d['x'] = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
d['y'] = pd.Series([11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66])
```

A working as expected classical loop approach:

```py
transformed = pd.DataFrame(columns=('x', 'y'))
for index, row in d.iterrows():
  transformed.loc[index] = [row[0] + 5, row[1] + 10]
print(transformed)
```

Produces:

```
    x   y
0   6  21
1   7  32
2   8  43
3   9  54
4  10  65
5  11  76
```

This is the `lambda` version:

```py
print(d.apply(lambda x: x + [5, 10]))
```

However, is raising the error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (2,)`

After reading [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), I understood my lambda approach should work. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: d.apply(..., axis=1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` is automatically column wise, the `axis` argument is set to 0 by default.

You need to specify `axis=1` for it will calculate row wise:

```
>>> d.apply(lambda x: x + [5, 10], axis=1)
    x   y
0   6  21
1   7  32
2   8  43
3   9  54
4  10  65
5  11  76
>>>
```

But tbh in this situation you don't need `apply` anyway:

```
>>> d + [5, 10]
    x   y
0   6  21
1   7  32
2   8  43
3   9  54
4  10  65
5  11  76
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

If number of columns is same like length of list simpliest is:

```
print(d + [5, 10])
    x   y
0   6  21
1   7  32
2   8  43
3   9  54
4  10  65
5  11  76
```

If there is multiple columns select by list, lengths of lists has to be same:

```
print(d[['x','y']] + [5, 10])
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt response.  I've accepted U12-forward's response because he/she touched on the main problem I faced, setting the `axis=1` argument in `apply`.  Even though your response is valid in a broader sense, it is infeasible for me to use `d + [5, 10]`  because I removed a lot of contexts of the real problem I was solving.  Again, thank you for your parsimonious response.

Comment: @Lourenco Thanks, apply is not recommended because slow - loops under the hood, if exist vectorized alternative like here. But is wide used, people like it, because think it will be faster, unfortunately obviously not.